# Fuelux spinner is not showing spinner on append to div event

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, spinner, fuelux

I am using fuelux spinner, it applies spinner when page loads but fails to apply spinners when I append HTML code containing spinner div's . CSS is also getting disturbed

```
<!-- Loaded spinner having button + and - to input box STARTS -->
<div class="shape-sp">
   <div class="spinner-my">
      <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" maxlength="1" class="spinner-input form-control">
          <div class="spinner-buttons input-group-btn btn-group-vertical">
          <button class="btn spinner-up btn-xs default" type="button">
             <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
           </button>
           <button class="btn spinner-down btn-xs default" type="button">
             <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
           </button>
           </div>
      </div>
   </div>                                                                   
</div>
```

```
HTMLCODE = /* It contains HTML code that will get appended to MYDIV */;
$("#mydiv").append(HTMLCODE);

<div id="mydiv"> </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to call `$('spinner-my').spinner();` on the element after you append. And you will need to use the .spinner class for CSS with .fuelux class at the top of the page/ as a parent.

Comment: I tried calling $('.spinner-mv').spinner(); after append. also added .fuelux on the main Div.....no luck

Comment: $('#MySpinner').spinner({
    value: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    step: 0.1
});  -------- Solved thanks